# react-native-appearance not listening to change event for First Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying a setup , So that when I change my System theme my react native app theme should also change.
I have use react navigation and react-native-appearance.
On app startup correct system theme is applied,  But when I change theme while using app for first time it doesn't.
But When I try to change system theme for second time it also changes app theme and works correctly.

here is my code :-

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {} from 'react-native';
import {AppearanceProvider} from 'react-native-appearance';
import Main from './main';

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <AppearanceProvider>
        <Main/>
    </AppearanceProvider>
  );
}
```

Main.js

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import {} from 'react-native';
import {Appearance} from 'react-native-appearance';
import {DarkTheme,DefaultTheme,NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from './home';

const myDarkTheme={
    ...DarkTheme,
    colors:{
        ...DarkTheme.colors,    
        text:"#fff",
        statusBarColor:"#000"
    }
  };
  
  const myLightTheme={
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors:{
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        text:"#000",
        statusBarColor:"rgb(242, 242, 242)"
    }
  };



export default function Main(){
    const [theme,setTheme]=useState();
    console.log(theme);
    
   const onThemeChange=()=>{
        const newColor=Appearance.getColorScheme();
        setTheme(newColor);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        onThemeChange()

        const subscription=Appearance.addChangeListener(()=>{
            onThemeChange()
        })

        return ()=>subscription.remove();
    },[])

    return(
        <NavigationContainer theme={theme === 'light' ? myLightTheme : myDarkTheme}>
            <Home/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

And Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import {useTheme} from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function Home(){
    const {colors}=useTheme();
    return (
      <View style={{...styles.container,backgroundColor:colors.background}}>
        <Text style={{color:colors.text}}>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <StatusBar barStyle={colors.statusBarColor==='#000' ? 'light-content':'dark-content'} backgroundColor={colors.background}/>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

Please help me So that theme Changes for first time also when I change system theme for first time after app startup.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

modify the **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.res.Configuration; // <--- import

// copy these lines
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  getReactInstanceManager().onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-appearance) Appearence.addChangeListener, is provided with the callback function which has colorScheme. You can use that to update the state directly, no need to call the onThemeChange() function again.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    onThemeChange();

    const subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(({ colorScheme }) => {
        setTheme(colorScheme);
    })

    return () => subscription.remove();
},[])
```

Comment: I have tried this already but still facing the issue Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open issue,

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28823

If you are using react-native then you can merge in the branch someone has provided on the above issue to fix it. But I am using Expo.

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwile to mention that, in case you are using a ***chrome based debugger*** the theme ***always*** will be ***light***. Either disable debugging or switch the debugger.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28823#issuecomment-640671784

> I was having the same problem with the hook only returning 'light', no
> matter how much I'd toggle the appearance in the simulator.
>
> After a lot of digging into code, it turned out the reason it was
> doing this was due to - the debugger! If you're using a Chrome-based
> debugger (either in browser or using the standalone RN debugger) the
> Appearance module will always return light, due to the debugger not
> being able to handle async functions (or something like that, it was a
> few days ago!).
>
> I can't say I understand the idiosyncracies as to why it does this,
> but the upshot of it all is I stopped using the Chrome debugger and
> moved to flipper - and it worked! I'm now able to swap between dark
> and light mode using the useColorTheme hook as expected.
>
> Hope this helps someone else, it was a head scratcher for me for quite
> a while!

Answer (score 0):

### For class component

```
import React from "react";

    import {
      SafeAreaView,
      Text,
      View,
      Dimensions,
      StyleSheet,
      TouchableHighlight,
      Image,
      ImageBackground,
      TextInput,
      TouchableOpacity,
      ScrollView,
      KeyboardAvoidingView,
      FlatList,
      Appearance,
      Animated,
    } from "react-native";

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      theme: false,
    };
  }

      componentDidMount() {
        Appearance.getColorScheme() == "dark"
          ? this.setState({ theme: true })
          : this.setState({ theme: false })
     
      }
    
    
      componentDidUpdate() {
        this.subscription=Appearance.addChangeListener((theme) => {
          // console.log("theme", theme);
          theme.colorScheme == "dark"
            ? this.setState({ theme: true })
            : this.setState({ theme: false });
        });
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.subscription.remove();
      }

    render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
          {
            padding: 1,
            flex: 1,
          },
          { backgroundColor: this.state.theme == true ? "#000" : "#fff" },
        ]}
  

    >
    )}
```

### For functional component

```
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);
     useEffect(() => {
        themeCheck();
      }, []);
    
      const themeCheck = async () => {
        const getScheme = await Appearance.getColorScheme();
        getScheme == "dark" ? setTheme(true) : setTheme(false);
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener((theme) => {
          // console.log("theme", theme);
          theme.colorScheme == "dark" ? setTheme(true) : setTheme(false);
        });
        return () => subscription.remove();
      },[])
 return (
    <>
      {/* <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" */}
      <SafeAreaView
        style={[
          styles.containerview1,
          { backgroundColor:theme == true ? "#000" : "#fff" },
        ]}
      ></SafeAreaView></>)
```